# Getting java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters trying to run Tests class

Tags: java, selenium, maven, junit, cucumber

Here's [dropbox_link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8fr97vueml3b5ps/AACsK3PE1DuVhPZOnRqiNwhba?dl=0), if someone wants to investigate.
Found myself in a pickle trying to run test scenario, intelliJ throws java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at first step, StepDefinition class down below:

```
package automation.glue;

import automation.config.AutomationFrameworkConfiguration;
import automation.drivers.DriverSingleton;
import automation.pages.CheckoutPage;
import automation.pages.HomePage;
import automation.pages.SignInPage;
import automation.utils.ConfigurationProperties;
import automation.utils.Constants;
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@ContextConfiguration(classes = AutomationFrameworkConfiguration.class)
public class StepDefinition {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private HomePage homePage;
    private SignInPage signInPage;
    private CheckoutPage checkoutPage;

    @Autowired
    ConfigurationProperties configurationProperties;

    @Before
    public void initializeObjects(){
        DriverSingleton.getInstance(configurationProperties.getBrowser());
        homePage = new HomePage();
        signInPage = new SignInPage();
        checkoutPage = new CheckoutPage();
    }

    @Given("^I go to the Website")
    public void i_go_to_the_Website(){
        driver = DriverSingleton.getDriver();
        driver.get(Constants.URL);
    }

    @When("^I click on Sign in button")
    public void i_click_on_sign_in_button(){
        homePage.clickSignIn();
    }

    @And("^I specify my credentials and click login")
    public void i_specify_my_credentials_and_click_login(){
        signInPage.logIn(configurationProperties.getEmail(), configurationProperties.getPassword());
    }

    @Then("^I can log into the website")
    public void i_can_log_into_the_website(){
        assertEquals(configurationProperties.getUsername(), homePage.getUserName());
    }
}
```

Seems like @Autowired doesn't want to inject instance of ConfigurationProperties in step definition, but I don't see why. Here's code of ConfigurationProperties:

```
package automation.utils;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@PropertySource("framework.properties")
public class ConfigurationProperties {

    @Value("${browser}")
    private String browser;

    @Value("${email}")
    private String email;

    @Value("${password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${username}")
    private String username;

    public String getBrowser() {
        return browser;
    }

    public void setBrowser(String browser) {
        this.browser = browser;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

And @ComponentScan searches folder "automation" for @Component which is in my AutomationFrameworkProperties class:

```
package automation.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("automation")
public class AutomationFrameworkConfiguration {
    public AutomationFrameworkConfiguration(){}
}
```

And to run all this I'm using RunTests:

```
package automation;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports"},
        features = "src/main/resources/features"
)
public class RunTests {
    @Test
    public void test(){}
}
```

After all this I'm getting this error:

```
C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.jdks\openjdk-17.0.1\bin\java.exe -ea -DnodeNamesHandler=org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberTestTreeNodeManager -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=51512:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\IdeaProjects\automationframework_laurentiu\target\test-classes;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\IdeaProjects\automationframework_laurentiu\target\classes;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\Downloads\jar_files_annotations_5.3\spring-beans-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\Downloads\jar_files_annotations_5.3\spring-core-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\Downloads\jar_files_annotations_5.3\spring-jcl-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-java\2.1.0\cucumber-java-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-core\2.1.0\cucumber-core-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-html\0.2.6\cucumber-html-0.2.6.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-jvm-deps\1.0.6\cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.6.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\gherkin\5.0.0\gherkin-5.0.0.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\tag-expressions\1.0.1\tag-expressions-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-junit\2.1.0\cucumber-junit-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-java\1.2.5\cucumber-java-1.2.5.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-core\1.2.5\cucumber-core-1.2.5.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-jvm-deps\1.0.5\cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.5.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\info\cukes\gherkin\2.12.2\gherkin-2.12.2.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-test-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-java\3.141.59\selenium-java-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\3.141.59\selenium-api-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\3.141.59\selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-edge-driver\3.141.59\selenium-edge-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\3.141.59\selenium-firefox-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\3.141.59\selenium-ie-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-opera-driver\3.141.59\selenium-opera-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\3.141.59\selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-safari-driver\3.141.59\selenium-safari-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-support\3.141.59\selenium-support-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.8.15\byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\25.0-jre\guava-25.0-jre.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-compat-qual\2.0.0\checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.1.3\error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.1\j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\animal-sniffer-annotations\1.14\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okhttp3\okhttp\3.11.0\okhttp-3.11.0.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okio\okio\1.14.0\okio-1.14.0.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\.m2\repository\com\github\jesg\phantomjsdriver\2.0.0\phantomjsdriver-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\dkreminskyi\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.3\plugins\cucumber-java\lib\cucumber-jvmFormatter.jar" com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 automation.RunTests
    Given I go to the Website                    # StepDefinition.i_go_to_the_Website()
      java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:807)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:530)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.<init>(LocalizedXStreams.java:76)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:48)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:40)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:102)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:83)
    at cucumber.api.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:58)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:80)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:140)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:68)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:23)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:73)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:99)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber$1.evaluate(Cucumber.java:108)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
    at ✽.I go to the Website(src/main/resources/features/Signin.feature:3)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @61e717c2
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields.locate(Fields.java:39)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter.<clinit>(TreeMapConverter.java:50)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:807)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:530)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.<init>(LocalizedXStreams.java:76)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:48)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:40)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:102)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:83)
    at cucumber.api.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:58)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:80)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:140)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:68)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:23)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:73)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:99)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber$1.evaluate(Cucumber.java:108)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)

    When I click on Sign in button               # StepDefinition.i_click_on_sign_in_button()
    And I specify my credentials and click login # StepDefinition.i_specify_my_credentials_and_click_login()
    Then I can log into the website              # StepDefinition.i_can_log_into_the_website()

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:807)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:530)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.<init>(LocalizedXStreams.java:76)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:48)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:40)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:102)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:83)
    at cucumber.api.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:58)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:80)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:140)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:68)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:23)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:73)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:99)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber$1.evaluate(Cucumber.java:108)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
    at ✽.I go to the Website(src/main/resources/features/Signin.feature:3)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @61e717c2
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields.locate(Fields.java:39)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter.<clinit>(TreeMapConverter.java:50)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:807)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:530)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.<init>(LocalizedXStreams.java:76)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:48)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:40)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:102)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:83)
    at cucumber.api.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:58)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:80)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:140)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:68)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:23)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:73)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:99)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber$1.evaluate(Cucumber.java:108)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)


Failed scenarios:
src/main/resources/features/Signin.feature:2 # Testing the authentication

1 Scenarios (1 failed)
4 Steps (1 failed, 3 skipped)
0m0.149s

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:807)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:530)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.<init>(LocalizedXStreams.java:76)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:48)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:40)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:102)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:83)
    at cucumber.api.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:58)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:80)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:140)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:68)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:23)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:73)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:99)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber$1.evaluate(Cucumber.java:108)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
    at ✽.I go to the Website(src/main/resources/features/Signin.feature:3)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @61e717c2
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields.locate(Fields.java:39)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter.<clinit>(TreeMapConverter.java:50)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:807)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:530)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.<init>(LocalizedXStreams.java:76)
    

Feature: Shopping Automation

  Scenario: Testing the authentication           # src/main/resources/features/Signin.feature:2

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Please, give any ideas, was watching course and other students getting same error from time to time, but no one figured this out yet. If someone can solve this they should be here.
Thanks.

Comment: The course you are following is probably using java 8. You are using 17. And and a very old version of Cucumber. Those don't work together.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a workaround to your problem.**

I am following a course to create an automation project for [automationpractice.com](http://automationpractice.com/) website.

There are some problems with this course, some dependencies are too old, so the first step is to upgrade them in the  [pom.xml](https://github.com/svascot/automation-practice/blob/master/pom.xml)

In the RunTests class complete the path where the report will be added, at the end of the route add the name of the file e.g. index.html or report.html.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports/report.html"},
        features = "src/main/resources/features"
)
public class RunTests {
    @Test
    public void test(){}
}
```

For some reason the Dependency Injection is not working, so a workaround to fix this problem is to work directly with the constants, in StepDefinition class:

```
//@Autowired
//ConfigurationProperties configurationProperties;

@Before
public void initializeObjects(){
    DriverSingleton.getInstance("Chrome");
    homePage = new HomePage();
    signInPage = new SignInPage();
    checkoutPage = new CheckoutPage();
}

@And("^I specify my credentials and click login")
public void i_specify_my_credentials_and_click_login(){
    signInPage.logIn("encodedEmail", "encodedExample");
}
```

With this changes the project can run and crate the report. I'll keep looking to fix the @Autowired problem.

Here is the link to my project If you want to check my code while I find the way to work with the Dependency Injection approach. https://github.com/svascot/automation-practice

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32287273)